# BitmapImage to StorageFile in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a BitmapImage by doing this:

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute))
```

But, because I am working with a Cortana App, I need to use StorageFile as the image type (very stupid imo, but that is how it is)

So, how can I transform that bitmap into the StorageFile I need, or how can I download an image through an URL into a StorageFile, because

```
StorageFle.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(Uri uri)
```

keeps popping an exception of "Value does not fall within the specified range"

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StorageFle.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` is used to get app resource.

To download a remote Uri as a `StorageFile`, use [StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.createstreamedfilefromuriasync).

```
var path = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png";
var file = await StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync(Path.GetFileName(path), 
    new Uri(path), null);
```

You can also save the file to disk check if it is downloaded correctly.

```
await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
```